# No page style appearing on Permissions page.

Tags: theming

The permissions page on my site has no styling/theme. It is the only administration page that has this problem. The page displays as if I have turned off styles. I am using Drupal 7. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: did you check your administrator theme?

Comment: I'm using Seven, it is up to date. I don't seem to be having problems with it except for the one page.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to do the following:

- delete css files under /sites/default/files/css and then checkout the administrator pages
- go to /admin/appearance and select an administrator them at the bottom of the page. If its already been selected try to use another administrator theme
- make sure "Use the administration theme when editing or creating content" is checked
- clear your cache using drupal clear cache button under /admin/config/development/performance
- Checkout Administer themes permission in the permission page /admin/people/permissions
- try to open your site with another browser

Comment: I've tried all of the above and it still seems to be having the same problem on the permissions page, even with different administration themes. However, thank you very much for your detailed response!

Comment: have you tried to rebuild drupal permissions, maybe it will solve your problem, I'm not sure about it though.